# Update a Column from another Column using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a DB with two columns with many records and from these two columns I have to do some mathematical operations and create other two columns.

For now I did like this:

- I made a SELECT and read the two columns, and put everything in a List
- Then I go through the List and UPDATE the table line by line

Do you think there is a faster way to do it? I also tried like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET X_GAUSS = (SELECT X FROM myTable ) + 1, Y_GAUSS = (SELECT Y FROM myTable) + 2
```

(it's only an example)

But in this way every line of the new columns is the same as the line before, instead I want something like:

```
X  Y  X_GAUSS Y_GAUSS
1  2  2       4
3  4  4       6
5  6  6       8
...
```

Comment: If you only want to update columns with values from other columns _from the same row_, then you don’t need to use SELECT here at all, you can simply use the columns directly in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: But I have to apply a function to X and Y to get X_GAUSS and Y_GAUSS...

Comment: I don’t see any functions in your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A subquery like `SELECT X FROM myTable` returns the *first* row of the table.

You can simply access the columns of the same row directly:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET X_GAUSS = X + 1,
    Y_GAUSS = Y + 2;
```